# Laravel 10 Passport returns a token object, but not a token

Tags: php, laravel, oauth-2.0, laravel-passport, laravel-10

I'm trying to do OAuth2 authorization on Laravel 10 using the API. Registration and authorization works, but I can't get a token either during registration or authorization. It would be correct to say that I am not receiving the token in the form in which it can be used in further requests. See `data.access_token`:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "data": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Schizo",
        "email": "********@gmail.com",
        "access_token": {
            "name": "DesktopClient",
            "abilities": [
                "*"
            ],
            "expires_at": null,
            "tokenable_id": 1,
            "tokenable_type": "App\\Models\\User",
            "updated_at": "2023-07-08T16:22:30.000000Z",
            "created_at": "2023-07-08T16:22:30.000000Z",
            "id": 2
        }
    },
    "message": "User login successfully."
}
```

I expect to see the token in this form:

[image]

### Versions

- PHP 8.1.21
- Laravel Framework 10.14.1
- Laravel Passport 11.8.8

### Some general information

Before the test, the command to create a personal access client was executed:

```
php artisan passport:client --personal --no-interaction
```

Command output:

```
Personal access client created successfully.
Client ID: 16
Client secret: KjpvwyB1XMZTfh8aFZzrSJZrb3di83JZsj6ZvRud
```

After that in the database, a row was created in the `oauth_clients` table:
[image]

and in `oauth_personal_access_clients` table:
[image]

Then I added the id and secret key to the .env file.

> .env

```
PASSPORT_PERSONAL_ACCESS_CLIENT_ID=16
PASSPORT_PERSONAL_ACCESS_CLIENT_SECRET=KjpvwyB1XMZTfh8aFZzrSJZrb3di83JZsj6ZvRud
```

> config/auth.php

```
return [
    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'passport',
            'provider' => 'users',
            'hash' => true,
        ],
    ],
];
```

> routes/api.php

```
Route::post('register', [AuthController::class, 'register']);
Route::post('login', [AuthController::class, 'login']);
```

> app/Http/Controllers/AuthController.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api;

use App\Http\Requests\ApiLoginRequest;
use App\Http\Requests\ApiRegisterRequest;
use App\Http\Resources\UserResource;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class AuthController extends ApiController
{
    /**
     * Performs user registration.
     *
     * @param ApiRegisterRequest $apiRegisterRequest
     * @return JsonResponse
     */
    public function register(ApiRegisterRequest $apiRegisterRequest): JsonResponse
    {
        $input = $apiRegisterRequest->validated();
        $input['password'] = bcrypt($input['password']);

        return $this->sendResponse(
            $this->getUserResourceWithAccessToken(User::create($input)),
            'User register successfully.'
        );
    }

    /**
     * Performs user authorization.
     *
     * @param ApiLoginRequest $apiLoginRequest
     * @return JsonResponse
     */
    public function login(ApiLoginRequest $apiLoginRequest): JsonResponse
    {
        if (!Auth::attempt($apiLoginRequest->validated())) {
            return $this->sendError('Unauthorised.', [
                'error' => 'Unauthorised.'
            ]);
        } else {
            return $this->sendResponse(
                $this->getUserResourceWithAccessToken(Auth::user()),
                'User login successfully.'
            );
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns compressed user data with an access token.
     *
     * @param User $user
     * @return UserResource
     */
    private function getUserResourceWithAccessToken(User $user): UserResource
    {
        return new UserResource(array_merge($user->getAttributes(), [
            'access_token' => $user->createToken('X-Soft Personal Access Client')->accessToken,
        ]));
    }
}
```

> app/Http/Controllers/ApiController.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse;

class ApiController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Success response method.
     *
     * @param mixed $result
     * @param string $message
     * @return JsonResponse
     */
    public function sendResponse(mixed $result, string $message): JsonResponse
    {
        return response()->json([
            'success' => true,
            'data' => $result,
            'message' => $message,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Return error response.
     *
     * @param string $error
     * @param array $errorMessages
     * @param int $code
     * @return JsonResponse
     */
    public function sendError(string $error, array $errorMessages = [], int $code = 404): JsonResponse
    {
        $response = [
            'success' => false,
            'message' => $error,
        ];

        if (!empty($errorMessages)) {
            $response['data'] = $errorMessages;
        }

        return response()->json($response, $code);
    }
}
```

I was advised to add the `api_token` field in the users table, since in the file config/auth.php the `guards.api.provider` parameter specifies `users`. However, this did not help solve the problem, which is obvious. I tried to completely repeat the algorithm of actions described in [this article](https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-10-rest-api-with-passport-authentication-tutorialexample.html).

Comment: Can you try ?

    private function getUserResourceWithAccessToken(User $user): UserResource
    {
        return new UserResource(array_merge($user->getAttributes(), [
            'access_token' => $user->createToken('X-Soft Personal Access Client')->plainTextToken,
        ]));
    }

Comment: @ArifulIslam, this will return a token for Laravel Sanctum in the format `ID|TOKEN`. Such a token will not work with a Laravel Passport.

Answer (score 2):

First check in your User model namespace should like this if you need direct token

```
use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens;
```

Not

```
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;
```

If you need a robust OAuth2 implementation with features like authorization codes, token refreshing, and third-party application integration, go for Passport (`use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens`).

If your application is relatively simple and you want quick, stateless API authentication, especially for SPAs and mobile apps, Sanctum (`use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens`) might be the better choice. And it can be access by

```
$access_toekn = $user->createToken('X-Soft Personal Access Client')->accessToken;
$token = $access_toekn->token;
```

Answer (score 0):

please check your User Models,
user model should have HasApiTokens

Comment: The model has this trait.

Comment: Please use the comments, if you do not really know the answer of the question.